# How to display top 5 along with custom in Tableau?

Tags: data-visualization, tableau-api

I am creating a dashboard which will display sales of top 5 products along with particular product in a category as per the filters. I have created top 5 category list using rank basis sales but am not able to club top 5 along with one specific category. This dashboard's objective is to compare industry vs our product in the category. Our product may or may not be in top 5.

I have tried using two different sheets and clubbing it together but it is not getting along properly.

For eg. The filters are set on TV.

Highest selling top 5 TVs will be displayed along with the in-house product as rows and column is sales. Can someone help.

Comment: Maybe you give an example of what you have, what you want and a piece of your effort.

Comment: show dummy data and final output